# UITableview inside UIScroll view - Disable scroll of scrollview when touching tableview

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a UITableview which is added as a subview to the uiscrollview. The table view Iam making it horizontal by rotating. So I can scroll the tableview horizontally. And my scrollview itself a horizontal scroll is there. Now the problem is when Iam scrolling my tableview, and reached last row, it is scrolling the Scrollview itself. I wnt to disable the scroll of the scrollview when Iam touching the Tableview. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your TableView on another ScrollView
And then when you use your inner scroll view, set outterScrollView scrollingEnabled to NO.

Answer (score 0):

Decrees the content height of uiscrollview

```
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollView.contentSize.width, 200)];
```

you can set height of tableview instead of 200.